# How to display BooleanField name in template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

**models:**

```
completed = models.BooleanField(_('Completed'))
```

**template:**

```
{% if object.completed %}
    <strong>{{ object.completed }}</strong>
{% endif %}
```

**outputs:**

```
<strong>True</strong>
```

**what I need:**

```
<strong>Completed</strong>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Also, check out [`yesno`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#yesno) template filter. Usage:

```
<strong>{{ object.completed|yesno:"Completed,Uncomplited" }}</strong>
```

or:

```
<strong>{{ object.completed|yesno:"Completed," }}</strong>
```

### UPDATE:

On other hand, you can always make your own template filter. For example, the next one returns a `verbose_name` of specified field:

**foo_tags.py:**

```
@register.filter()
def get_field_name(object, field):
    verbose_name = object._meta.get_field(field).verbose_name
    return verbose_name
```

**template.html:**

```
{% if object.completed %}
    <strong>{{ object|get_field_name:'completed' }}</strong>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This shows extra `<strong>` when the value is `False`. If you don't want to use more clear `{% if %}...{% endif %}`, you could try `{{ object.completed|yesno:"<strong>Completed</strong>,"|safe }}` (well, `yesno` is not that suitable for the usage...)

Comment: While I like this filter it won't work in my case. The goal is to have string "Completed" in one place (model) and re-use it in templates.

Comment: @Terra how about writting your own template filter. See my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

```
{% if object.completed %}<strong>Completed</strong>{% endif %}
```

Comment: This is what I currently have. I just translated the string within the template _('Completed'). However, this is not DRY as the BooleanField has the name within the field definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add label property to form field:

```
completed = forms.BooleanField(label=mark_safe('<strong>Completed</strong>'))
```

When you will use `{{ form.completed.label }}` you will have `<label><strong>Completed</strong></label>`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get that using object instance. If you have a `modelForm` for that model in the template the you can use `{{form.completed.label}}`

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use:

```
{% if object.completed %}
    <p><strong>Completed</stromg></p>
{% else %}
    <p><strong>Not Completed</strong></p>
{% endif %}
```